# С помощью sql запросов вытащить повторяющиеся значения 1 раз

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Имеется таблица с двумя столбцами на удаленном сервере.

[image]

Необходимо вытащить из данной таблицы каждую пару один раз без повторений. То есть необходимо получить таблицу со строками A-0, A-1, B-0, B-1  и тд

Comment: `select distinct column1, column2 from table_name` ?

Comment: @MaxU да, сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [предикат `DISTINCT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) чтобы извлечь строки без повторов (т.е. каждый набор значений для указанных столбцов в результирующей выборке будет уникальным):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ...
FROM table_name
...
```